# In pandas how to filter based on a particular weekday and range of time

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame looks something like this.The notebook is [here](https://wakari.io/sharing/bundle/cam/Final%20turnstile)

```
     C/A  UNIT       SCP     DATEn     TIMEn    DESCn  ENTRIESn   EXITSn  
0   A002  R051  02-00-00  08-18-12  00:00:00  REGULAR   3759779  1297676   
1   A002  R051  02-00-00  08-18-12  04:00:00  REGULAR   3759809  1297680   
2   A002  R051  02-00-00  08-18-12  08:00:00  REGULAR   3759820  1297701   
3   A002  R051  02-00-00  08-18-12  12:00:00  REGULAR   3759879  1297799   
4   A002  R051  02-00-00  08-18-12  16:00:00  REGULAR   3760073  1297863   
5   A002  R051  02-00-00  08-18-12  20:00:00  REGULAR   3760367  1297920   
6   A002  R051  02-00-00  08-19-12  00:00:00  REGULAR   3760494  1297958   
7   A002  R051  02-00-00  08-19-12  04:00:00  REGULAR   3760525  1297962   
8   A002  R051  02-00-00  08-19-12  08:00:00  REGULAR   3760545  1297983   
9   A002  R051  02-00-00  08-19-12  12:00:00  REGULAR   3760603  1298048   
10  A002  R051  02-00-00  08-19-12  16:00:00  REGULAR   3760750  1298104   
11  A002  R051  02-00-00  08-19-12  20:00:00  REGULAR   3760982  1298137   
12  A002  R051  02-00-00  08-20-12  00:00:00  REGULAR   3761088  1298175   
13  A002  R051  02-00-00  08-20-12  04:00:00  REGULAR   3761098  1298186   
14  A002  R051  02-00-00  08-20-12  08:00:00  REGULAR   3761130  1298265
```

this code will filter out the month of july

```
july_station = df[['COUNTn']]\
           [(df.DATETIMEn >= datetime.datetime.strptime('07-01-13', '%m-%d-%y')) &\
            (df.DATETIMEn <= datetime.datetime.strptime('07-31-13', '%m-%d-%y'))]\
            .groupby(df.UNIT)\
            .sum()
```

The above code filters only the month

what if i have to filter out entries between midnight & 4am on Fridays in July 2013? Is this right approach?

```
 july_station1 = df[['COUNTn']]\
               [(df.DATETIMEn >= datetime.datetime.strptime('07-01-13 00:00 5', '%m-%d-%y %H:%M %A')) &\
                (df.DATETIMEn <= datetime.datetime.strptime('07-31-13 04:00 5', '%m-%d-%y %H:%M %A'))]\
                .groupby(df.UNIT)\
                .sum()
```

Comment: I don't see the columns 'COUNTn' or 'DATETIMEn' in your example dataframe.

Comment: link to the notebook https://wakari.io/sharing/bundle/cam/Final%20turnstile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your column is a datetime column, you can get weekday and hour with `column.dt.weekday` (monday = 0, sunday = 6), and `column.dt.hour`. Also you can use `between` on your series to do range comparison more elegantly:

```
df.DATEn = pd.to_datetime(df.DATEn)
df.TIMEn = pd.to_datetime(df.TIMEn)
mask = (df.DATEn == 4) & df.TIMEn.dt.hour.between(0,4)
```

Comment: Is there anything like
`df.DATEn.yr =='2014`

Comment: yes it's in `dt`, `df.DATEn.dt.year == 2014`, the full docs are at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/api.html#datetimelike-properties

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943913/pandas-how-to-find-all-zeros-in-a-column
Can you help me with this?