# pandas How to find all zeros in a column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import copy

head6= copy.deepcopy(df)

closed_day = head6[["DATEn","COUNTn"]]\
             .groupby(head6['DATEn']).sum()
print closed_day.head(10)
```

Output:

```
     COUNTn
DATEn               
06-29-13    11326823
06-30-13     5667746
07-01-13     8694140
07-02-13     7275701
07-03-13     9948824
07-04-13  1072542591
07-05-13     7867611
07-06-13     4733018
07-07-13     4838404
07-08-13    42962814
```

Now what if I want to find if `COUNTn` has any zeros and I want to return corresponding day? I've written something like this but I'm getting an error saying my df doesn't have any column called `COUNTn`

```
ndf = closed_day[["DATEn","COUNTn"]][closed_day.COUNTn == 0]
print ndf.head(1)
```

Comment: you're trying to filter the aggregated df, why not filter on the original df?

Comment: I want to see if the grouped `sum ==0`. In the original DF i know there are some zeros but i want to see the whole group has zeros or not

Comment: Sorry are asking if the aggregated sum `==0`? why not just do `closed_day == 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the groupby, COUNTn is converted into a Series, which doesn't have columns (it's just a single column). If you want to keep it as a dataframe, as your code is expecting, use `groupby(grouper, as_index=False)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982196/pandas-remove-a-row-when-a-particular-kind-of-value-appears-in-a-column